# Fixing Label on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

What is the best way to approach fixing a label on the bottom of the screen even while the user is scrolling through content? Unsure how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) for this purpose. Just attach it to the bottom and set the constraints.

- Vertical Spacing to Bottom
- Leading Spacing to Container Margin (if you want margin to the left)
- Trailing Space to Container Margin (if you want margin to the right)

To add a constraint

1. Select the element
2. Right click and drag to the direction you want to set the constraint

To change a constant

1. Select the contraint
2. Go to Attributes Inspector
3. Change the value in the constant field

[image]

Comment: Right. Don't know why I totally blanked on Auto Layout being the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually upon implementing Auto Layout, it doesn't fix a UILabel to the bottom of the screen on a TableView. When I scroll down, the rows go up, and the label follows. Is there any way I can keep it on the bottom? I know rows are added to the bottom when you scroll, so maybe there isnt?

Comment: You could place the tableView some pixels above the bottom and place the label in that area with Auto Layout. If you understand how I mean.

Comment: Is that doable with a tableview Controller?

Comment: edit: It seems like you cannot. Is it good practice to use a UIViewController and a tableView as opposed to a tableviewController?

Comment: I have created a sample project for you so that you can see how I have done this, download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svht5wpsak8jx9s/TableViewLabelAtBottom.zip?dl=0) and run it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks!